# AngularJS and Bootstrap input border focus

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to set original border color when user click outside input. When input focused, the border color change to red, and keep red until input validation is success.

This is a piace of my code:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <input id="user_name" type="email" name="user_name" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" ng-model="user.user_name" required="" class="form-control burger-input" maxlength="50" focus-me="" />
                <span class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback text-muted"></span>
                <span ng-show="form_submitted &amp;&amp; loginForm.user_name.$error.required" class="label label-danger">Questo campo è richiesto.</span>
                <span ng-show="form_submitted &amp;&amp; loginForm.user_name.$error.email" class="label label-danger">L'indirizzo e-mail dev'essere valido.</span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the input `'required'` attribute and `:focus`
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: I'm positive this isn't the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your CSS

```
      #user_name.ng-valid.ng-touched{
        border:thick green solid;
    }
    #user_name.ng-invalid{
        border:thick red solid;
    }
    #user_name.ng-pristine{
        border:thick grey solid;
    }

    #user_name.ng-valid{
    border:thick green solid;
    }
```

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/BSb7Yzfja2z7KCaKZl09?p=preview)

Based on the suggestion below by Dwijen, you can also apply this to a class.

```
.form-control.ng-valid.ng-touched{
    border:thick green solid;
}
.form-control.ng-invalid{
    border:thick red solid;
}
.form-control.ng-pristine{
    border:thick grey solid;
}

.form-control.ng-valid{
    border:thick green solid;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `#user_name` it would be better if you would apply the styles on the class `.form-control`.

Comment: Yes, that's a great suggestion. Adding it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. may be it satisfied your requirement

just add this css

```
.form-control.ng-pristine{
    border:2px grey solid;
}
.form-control.ng-valid{
    border:2px green solid;
}
.form-control.ng-invalid:focus {
  border:2px red solid;
}
```

[PLUNKER DEMO LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/qL4PycIDZoco4sxnDsRK?p=preview)